# build emacs and gnutls not found

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I built emacs26 on Ubuntu16.04, when I executed `./config --prefix=/usr/local/emacs` , it showed like this:

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
     gnutls
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
If you don't want to link with them give
     --with-gnutls=no
as options to configure
```

I tried to solve this problem many times, but failed. Who can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Building standard programs isn't in the scope of SO, which is for *programming* help.  Try [su] or perhaps [emacs.se] instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight Building programs generally may be off-topic, but as Emacs is a "software [tool] commonly used by programmers", this question [is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There is even a tag for it, which the OP has used.

Comment: Yes, there's a tag for programming (extending) Emacs and those questions are on topic here.  I don't believe that merely building Emacs is appropriate for that tag.  One could argue that `mv` is a tool commonly used by programmers, but doesn't make building/using it a programming question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The error message tells you two ways in which to solve your problem.

1. Install the `gnutls` development package. You can find it by doing: `apt-cache search 'libgnutls.*-dev'`, and then install it with `apt-get`.
2. Link without `gnutls`, a la `./config --prefix=/usr/local/emacs --with-gnutls=no`

Comment: Following these instructions, I installed `sudo apt install libgnutls28-dev` which worked on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

Comment: Here is the list packages I needed to build emacs in a container (use same release as host): `apt install wget make gcc libgnutls28-dev pkg-config libncurses-dev`

Answer (score 22):

The only thing that worked for me was installing pkg-config.

Comment: Same for me, had the dev package already installed but this is also required

Comment: Same for me installing `libgnutls28-dev` was only part of the solution. `pkg-config` is what got me over the hump.

Answer (score 9):

Fixed on CentOS:

```
yum install gnutls-devel
```

Answer (score 8):

For me on Ubuntu 19.10 it was specifically "libgnutls28-dev", all others didn't work.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnutls-dev says. It's necessary to install `libgnutls28-dev` package

Comment: This is also the correct answer for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

Actually this should not be too hard to fix. You didn't tell us what you have tried.
What happens if you call
`./configure --with-gnutls=no`

Normally this is one possibility to work around this.
Th other way would be to install libgnutls dev package. Just search for libgnutls with

```
apt-cache search libgnutls
```

and you should find the package. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and on my side it is `libgnutls28-dev`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I installed gnutls on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install gnutls-bin
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuTLS

Comment: It's probably more appropriate to install the `-dev` package, for building other programs?

Comment: If you actually want to do development on `gnutls-bin`, then yes, install the `-dev` package.  If you just want to build emacs, then only `gnutls-bin` is necessary.

Comment: Actually, @TobySpeight is right.  If you want to do development on `gnutls`, you'd clone from here: https://github.com/gnutls/gnutls.  The `-dev` package contains the required header and library files, as seen here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgnutls28-dev/filelist.